# Redirecting in Angular using $window.location.href works if invoked directly, but not if called from another function

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

I'm trying to redirect from my Angular app to a non-angular page.  If I have a redirect function on the $scope and invoke it directly from a UI element via ng-click it works as expected.  If I call the function from within another $scope function, though, the page reloads or remains as is.  I suspect there is a scoping issue here, but I can't tell what it is.  I also tried $window.location.assign() and got the same result.

Why is the redirect working one way, but not the other?  Thanks!

[Link to CodePen](http://codepen.io/scottmcd/pen/ZYMpEZ)

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
  $scope.destination = "http://www.clientsfromhell.net";
  $scope.redirectStarted = false;

  $scope.redirect = function(target){
    $window.location.href = target;
    $scope.redirectStarted = true;
  };

  $scope.wrapperFunction = function() {
    var altDestination = "http://www.reddit.com/r/CrappyDesign";
    $scope.redirect(altDestination);
  };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li>Invoke redirect() directly: <input type="button" value="Direct Invocation" data-ng-click="redirect(destination)" /></li>
    <li>Invoke from wrapper function: <input type="button" value="From Wrapper" data-ng-click="wrapperFunction()" /></li>
  </ul>
  <div data-ng-show="redirectStarted">
    Redirect started
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

dfsq was right that my problem was not related to Angular.  My app is a .NET application, and there was a form on the master page.  Because I was using a button of type=submit, the form was being submitted, which cancels the redirect unless you do a preventDefault() on it.  In my debugging, I was using an ng-click function on a header element to do the redirect.  That worked fine because it didn't submit the form, but it also led me down the wrong path in thinking it was a scoping problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular. The reason why the wrapper redirect is not working, is that it is using different redirect URL (on `reddit` domain). This resource has restricted content policy preventing it from being displayed in iframe on different domain pages.

Сorresponding error:

> Refused to display 'http://www.reddit.com/r/CrappyDesign' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

The first destination URL doesn't have this limitation, so it works flawlessly.

From documentation about [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options):

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a ,  or  . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

Comment: Makes sense, and updating the Pen makes it work as as it should.  It probably means that I didn't reproduce the problem I thought I did in my app, though I'll keep working on it.  Thanks!